# Finding index from a list for a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list containing one of four symbolic codes and would like to assign a number to each based on the index for each element in a second list "dictionary' containing one of each code.

```
typecode = Table[i, {i, 4}]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)

typestrings = {"AA", "Aa", "aA", "aa"}

(* {"AA", "Aa", "aA", "aa"} *)

alist = RandomChoice[typestrings, 10]

(* {"Aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "Aa", "aA", "AA", "AA", "aa", "aA"} *)

Table[Extract[ 
        typecode , 
        Flatten[Position[typestrings, alist[[i]] ]] 
        ] , {i, 10 } ]

(* {2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3} *)
```

works but feels awfully inelegant. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `Association` as dictionary:

```
typecode = Table[i, {i, 4}];
typestrings = {"AA", "Aa", "aA", "aa"};
dictionary = AssociationThread[typestrings, typecode]

RandomSeed[666];
alist = RandomChoice[typestrings, 10000];

a = Table[
     Extract[typecode, 
      Flatten[Position[typestrings, alist[[i]]]]], {i, 
      Length[alist]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Lookup[dictionary, alist]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> <|"AA" -> 1, "Aa" -> 2, "aA" -> 3, "aa" -> 4|>
>
> 0.043401
>
> 0.000695
>
> True

As you can see, this is also *much* faster.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This is good.

Comment: @jmm As a courtesy, remember to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Henrik's answer if you choose it.

Comment: @jmm You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

```
alist /. Thread[typestrings -> typecode]
```

> {2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3}